# How to schedule Batch Execution Service of Azure Machine Learning in Azure Scheduler

Tags: azure, machine-learning, batch-processing, azure-scheduler, azure-machine-learning-service

In Batch execution API help page of Azure Machine Learning there are three different URI’s

- Submit Job (Response is Job ID)
- Start Job ( we need to use the above Job ID in this URI)
- Get Status or Result (we need to use the above Job ID in this URI)

How do I automate these jobs in the Azure Scheduler? (i.e. if I want to execute the BES on the particular date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use Azure Data Factory instead of the scheduler. This would allow you to schedule the BES call into the future while identifying where the result file will end up.

There are lots of examples online on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think Azure Data factory is the best way to schedule the BES calls.
you can schedule your activities using data factory and pipeline.

following links are useful:

[Updating Azure Machine Learning models using Update Resource Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-ml-update-resource-activity)

[Getting started with Azure Data Factory and Azure Machine Learning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/getting-started-with-azure-data-factory-and-azure-machine-learning-4/)